# Does value get converted when inserted into database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I was curious if androids SQLiteDatabase insert method automatically handles type conversion.

Here is my example:

I have a csv file with a column name of age. Its type will be an INTEGER.

Lets say I have already created the database and table.

Now I am parsing the csv file with CSVReader, which parses each line and inserts each value into an index of a String[].

In order to insert each line of data into the database, I have to use a ContentValue object, which allows me to store values in it.

```
//Parse each line and store in line...

ContentValue values = new ContentValue();
values.put(KEY_AGE, line[1]); // Assume line[1] is the age 

database.insert(table, null, values);
```

If I store the age value as a string (as seen above), and then insert it into the table, does Android handle the conversion to INTEGER before inserting it into the database?

I am asking this because I am trying to insert a bunch of tables into a database, and it looks much cleaner when I can just iterate through an array then explicitly state each put call, i.e:

Also if anyone has any design suggestions feel free to tell me.

CLEAN

```
int i = 0;
for(String s : TransitContract.Routes.COLUMN_ARRAY) {
    values.put(s, line[i]);
    i++;
}
```

UGLY

```
values.put(TransitContract.Routes.KEY_ROUTE_ID, line[0]);
values.put(TransitContract.Routes.KEY_AGENCY_ID, line[1]);
values.put(TransitContract.Routes.KEY_SHORT_NAME, line[2]);
values.put(TransitContract.Routes.KEY_LONG_NAME, line[3]);
values.put(TransitContract.Routes.KEY_DESCRIPTION, line[4]);
values.put(TransitContract.Routes.KEY_ROUTE_TYPE, Integer.parseInt(line[5]));
values.put(TransitContract.Routes.KEY_URL, line[6]);
values.put(TransitContract.Routes.KEY_COLOR, line[7]);
values.put(TransitContract.Routes.KEY_TEXT_COLOR, line[8]);

return mDatabase.insert(TransitContract.Routes.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a column as `INTEGER`, SQLite will automatically convert strings to numbers, if possible.

See the documentation for [Type Affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity).

Answer (score 1):

If your `ContentProvider` doesn't restrict it (i.e. pass it directly to the `SQLiteDatabase.insert()` method), it should work. SQLite is not that picky about the types used in queries/inserts and the actual column type.

However, it would be best practice to parse and check the values before inserting. Otherwise you might actually insert a string which can't be parsed as integer and therefore retrieving the value might fail.

**References:**

- [Boolean datatype accepting string value and integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772028/boolean-datatype-accepting-string-value-and-integer-value)
- [SQLite table with integer column stores string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830248/sqlite-table-with-integer-column-stores-string)

Comment: I am doing all of this inside my SQLiteOpenHelper subclass's onCreate, so the ContentProvider doesn't even come into play, right?

These are not inserts done through the ContentProvider. These are inserts done directly to the database when it is being first initialized by my SQLiteOpenhelper.


BTW I think I am just going to let SQLite handle it because the data I am getting has already been type checked.

Comment: Since `SQLiteOpenHelper` passes an `SQLiteDatabase` instance as argument, it should work the way you want.